# Show integral of sequence of functions is equicontinuous.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, equicontinuity

Let $f_n : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and uniformly bounded. Define
$$g_n(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f_n(s) ds, \ \ x \in [a,b], \ n \geq 1.$$
Show that $g_n(\cdot)$ is equicontinuous.

We must show that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta(x_0, \epsilon)$ such that for every $n$ and for every $x_0 \in [a,b]$,  $$|g_n(x) - g_n(x_0)| < \epsilon, \ \ \text{whenever} \ \  |x-x_0| < \delta.$$

$$|g_n(x) - g_n(x_0)| = | \int_{a}^{x} f_n(s) ds - \int_{a}^{x_0} f_n(s) ds | $$ $$ \leq |\int_{a}^{\delta + x_0} f_n(s) ds - \int_{a}^{x_0} f_n(s) ds| = |\int_{a}^{\delta} f_n(s) ds|.$$

Since $f_n$ is uniformly bounded, we know that $|f_n(x)| \leq M$ for all $n$. So, 
$$|\int_{a}^{\delta} f_n(s) ds| \leq \int_{a}^{\delta} |f_n(s)| ds \leq M(\delta-a).$$

So, for $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{M} + a$, we have that $|g_n(x) - g_n(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

Does this look right? I honestly haven't done problems involving integrals in forever, so I am not sure if every step I did is valid? I would be very happy if someone could verify.

Comment: That integral at the end should be $\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\delta},$ not $\int_a^\delta.$ Otherwise it looks good. There is a different approach: The FTC shows $g_n'= f_n.$ A function whose derivative is bounded by $M$ in absolute value satisfies a Lipschitz condition, which is perfect for equicontinuity.